# How to convert ms office spreadsheet xml content into xlsx in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, xml, excel, silverlight

I have spread sheet XML like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ss:Workbook xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
    <ss:Styles>
        <ss:Style ss:ID="1">
            <ss:Font ss:Bold="1"/>
        </ss:Style>
    </ss:Styles>
    <ss:Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
        <ss:Table>
            <ss:Column ss:Width="80"/>
            <ss:Column ss:Width="80"/>
            <ss:Column ss:Width="80"/>
            <ss:Row ss:StyleID="1">
                <ss:Cell>
                    <ss:Data ss:Type="String">First Name</ss:Data>
                </ss:Cell>
                <ss:Cell>
                    <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Last Name</ss:Data>
                </ss:Cell>
                <ss:Cell>
                    <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Phone Number</ss:Data>
                </ss:Cell>
            </ss:Row>          

            <ss:Row>
                <ss:Cell>
                    <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Kevin</ss:Data>
                </ss:Cell>
                <ss:Cell>
                    <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Boske</ss:Data>
                </ss:Cell>
                <ss:Cell>
                    <ss:Data ss:Type="String">(425) 123-4567</ss:Data>
                </ss:Cell>
            </ss:Row>
        </ss:Table>
    </ss:Worksheet>
</ss:Workbook>
```

I want to convert this xml to xlsx.

What i tried is

```
private void btnExport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            SaveFileDialog Savedlg = new SaveFileDialog();
            Savedlg.Filter = "XLS (.xls)|*.xls|xlsx (.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
            byte[] xlfile = this.byts;
            if ((bool)Savedlg.ShowDialog())
            {
                System.IO.MemoryStream mStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                mStream.Write(xlfile, 0, xlfile.Length);
                Stream fileStream = Savedlg.OpenFile();
                mStream.WriteTo(fileStream);
                fileStream.Close();
            }



    }

    byte[] byts = null;
    private void import_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();           
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        System.IO.Stream fileStream = openFileDialog1.File.OpenRead();           
       this.byts= ReadFully(fileStream);
    }

    public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Save as XLS works fine, when open that files in EXCEL it shows a msg like

"the file you are trying to open is in a different format then specified by the file extension".

Saving as XLSX is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading the xml file, using `XmlReader` or `XDocument` or `XmlDocument` classes. Then using [Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30425), you can create an excel file.

Open XML SDK has a high learning curve. So you might also want to look at [Closed XML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/), which is a wrapper around Open XML SDK and has a gentler learning curve.

Comment: it is a silverlight app,so it wont support the open xml sdk